# Element size is bigger than others despite include same content in mapping

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, mapping

Mapping return 4 elements of an array includes icon,title,description. Despite all have same content, one of them is bigger than others.

[image]

Here is the mapping function

```
<div className=" grid grid-cols-2 space-x-5 p-3 space-y-3  mt-16  justify-center">
         {cards.map((element) => {
          return (
            <div className=" feature-card1 ">
              <div className="content">
                <div className="front">
                  // here is the card content
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

`
Here is the CSS :

```
.feature-card1 {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 320px;

  perspective: 1000px;
}
.feature-card1:hover .content {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.feature-card1 .content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

I would be happy if you try to solve it, thanks.

Comment: Please create a proper [mre].

Comment: Can you share your container style of feature card?

Comment: @MithatErcan it is on the top row.

Comment: You can use gap for grid like this grid grid-cols-2 m-1 gap-3 p-3  mt-16  justify-center

Comment: @MithatErcan it worked for me, thanks abi :)